# how Do I Implement stripe payment functionality in flutter desktop app

Tags: flutter

I have tried searching for packages that work on desktop but haven found any All the packages have seen so far none is for desktop

A solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

While the [official Stripe Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe) doesn't support Desktop, you could work with the REST-Api with a standard HTML-Client.

You can find more here: https://stripe.com/docs/api